# @Async not working for method having return type void

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-annotations

I wanted to make a method writing to DB as async using `@Async` annotation.

I marked the class with the annotation `@EnableAsync`:

```
@EnableAsync
public class FacialRecognitionAsyncImpl {

    @Async
    public void populateDataInPushQueue(int mediaId, int studentId) {
        //myCode
    }
}
```

while calling the `populateDataInPushQueue` method, the write operation should be executed in another thread and the flow should continue from the class I am calling this method. But this is not happening and the program execution is waiting for this method to complete.

Comment: Can you post the code invoking the method ?

Comment: Can you place @Configuration on top of the class?

Comment: Is it working for non void ?

Comment: didn't try for non void

Answer (score 12):

The [`@Async`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) annotation has few limitations - check whether those are respected:

- it must be applied to `public` methods only
- it cannot be called from the same class as defined
- the return type must be either `void` or [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

The following can be found at the documentation of [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html):

> Please note that proxy mode allows for the interception of calls through the proxy only; local calls within the same class cannot get intercepted that way.

Another fact is that the class annotated with [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html) must be a [`@Configuration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) as well. Therefore start with an empty class:

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration { }
```

Comment: Nope.... not working. one thing to note here is that I am calling this method from the service layer and not the controller. Also do i have to put these annotations to the service layer class(from where i am calling this method)

Comment: FacialRecognitionAsyncImpl daoService = new FacialRecognitionAsyncImpl();
                daoService.populateDataInPushQueue(mediaId, studentId);

Comment: You can't just instantiate a new instance of `FacialRecognitionAsyncImpl` and then call the async method.  The async functionality **only** exists on the Spring proxy object that is created when Spring initializes the application context.  You need to make `FacialRecognitionAsyncImpl` a Spring-managed component (by annotating it with `@Component`, or an equivalent annotation), using `@Autowire` to inject the component into a class in the server layer, and then calling the async method on that injected instance, which will be a Spring-managed proxy.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, you are missing `@Configuration` annotation and your async service is not component scanned. Here is an example code fragment that should do the trick:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync  //should be placed together.
public class FacialRecognitionAsyncService {

     @Async
     public void populateDataInPushQueue(int mediaId, int studentId) {
         //myCode
     }
} 

@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class FacialServiceConfig {

    // this will make your service to be scanned.
    @Bean
    public FacialRecognitionAsyncService createFacialRecognitionService() {
        return new FacialRecognitionAsyncService();
    }

}
```

Now the service bean that is invoking the async method. Notice that it has been dependency injected. This way spring AOP proxies will be invoked on each invocation fo the `facialService`. Spring uses AOP in the back scenes in order to implement `@Async`.

```
@Service
public class MyBusinessService {

@Autowire
FacialRecognitionAsyncService  facialService;

public myBusinessMethod() {
   facialService.populateDataInPushQueue()
}
```

Notice that `FacialService` is injected in `MyService` through dependency injection.

Comment: Nope.... not working. one thing to note here is that I am calling this method from the service layer and not the controller. Also do i have to put these annotations to the service layer class(from where i am calling this method)

Comment: @DhruvSinghChandel  notice that the bean FacialRecognitionAsyncService   is injected with dependency injection. This is very important because the Async is based on aspects.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov shouldn't `FacialRecognitionAsyncService` class be annotated only with `@Service` or `@Component` instead since [Async Docs page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) states that methods annotated with `@Async` can't be used in same class which is annotated with `@Configuration`?